# How/why is it possible for a body to produce gallstones -- yrs after gallbladder was removed?

Tags: gallbladder, gallstone, bile-biliary-duct

I had my gallbladder removed a few years ago because I developed pancreatitis out of the blue and my pancreas hemorrhaged... and they never figured it out... so they assumed it was probably a gallstone that perforated my pancreas.

But in the Urgent Care today -- the doctor was telling me that he still suspected that my pain was still caused by gallbladder complications? Like I still had stones in my bile-ducts?

How is that possible?? My gallbladder was removed 9 years ago.

Anyway, I am having an ultrasound to confirm the findings of gallstones (or kidney stones), but even if they found gallstones, what then do they do? Since the gallbladder was already removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, they never officially confirmed if the problem 9 years ago was from *gallstones?*

After the gallbladder is removed, a doctor usually cuts it and checks if there is any stone in it, so if it were, you would probably know.

When you have gallstones in the gallbladder you can have additional ones in the ducts. Theoretically, it is possible that a surgeon removes the gallbladder with stones, but some stone remains hidden in the ducts. Ultrasound should detect this. At next ultrasound, you can ask a doctor if any gallstones are mentioned in your medical documentation.

If they find a gallstone in a common bile duct, they can remove it by a type of upper endoscopy called [**ERCP**](http://www.ddc.musc.edu/public/procedures/ERCP.html).

Another quite common cause of the gallbladder-like pain after gallbladder removal is **biliary dyskinesia,** or more specifically **[sphincter of Oddi dysfunction (SOD)](http://www.iffgd.org/upper-gi-disorders/sphincter-of-oddi-dysfunction.html),** which can be due to a spasm of the muscular sphincter at the end of the common bile duct (where it opens into the duodenum). The exact cause is not known, but may be partly psychosomatic or related to certain foods (a bit like in IBS). The pain in SOD appears in the upper right abdominal quadrant (usually just at the bottom of the rib cage), builds up to a steady level and then remains constant and lasts at least 30 minutes.

It is also possible that the original problem may not be associated with the bile ducts but with the pancreas. Pancreas can produce [**pancreatic stones**](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10464344), which can block the pancreatic duct and cause pancreatitis. These stones can be also removed by ERCP.